# Disable logging for a particular ansible-playbook

Tags: logging, command-line, ansible, disable

My Ansible configuration file ansible.cfg contains: `log_path=ansible.log`

Therefore, logging is enabled. But I want the above configuration to be overridden for a particular playbook, ie logging to be disabled for just one playbook. Is something of this sort possible:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/hosts.ini <logging=None>
```

Is it possible to override logging config and disable it at playbook level or using command line?

As per [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-log-path),
environment variable `ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH` can override log_path in ansible.cfg file, but that doesn't seem to help in disabling logging temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

Empty [DEFAULT_LOG_PATH](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-log-path) disables logging. [Environment variables have a higher precedence than entries in ansible.cfg](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#:%7E:text=Environment%20variables%20have%20a%20higher,cfg%20file%20Ansible%20loads.). Try

```sh
ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH=" " ansible-playbook playbook.yml
```

Comment: I had tried this, this didn't work for me. It gives 'IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: u' /home/mluser/app. Seems like this actually tries to assign current directory as the log path

Comment: ANSIBLE_LOG_PATH= "  " (space in between quotes) worked for me though!